# Auto Update Chart with Data

Tags: macros, vlookup

I want to find a way of pulling data from one table to another.

Each week I have a list of new data that I need to place into a master file. The rows have the item and the columns are the week numbers.

I want to be able to cross reference the items on the new data, if it finds it in the main file it will drag the quantity over and place it in the column for the next week.

Currently I pull off the data and manually update the master file one by one.

I have looked at vlookup functions and index/match but I am struggling to get it to pull the data across.

A macro would be easiest so I can collate the new data, press a macro enabled button and this will place all the data in the correct rows and columns.

Any help would be appreciated